# Whoosh: How to get search excerpts as a list

Tags: python, whoosh

From the [Whoosh documentation](https://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/highlight.html) I can get matched search terms with some context with:

```
results = mysearcher.search(myquery)
for hit in results:
    print(hit["title"])
    # Assume "content" field is stored
    print(hit.highlights("content"))
```

I'd like to access the "highlights" as a list of separated items (so that I can enumerate them in a html list) but the output of `hit.highlights()` appears to be of type `<class 'str'>`, and it's not clear to me that there's a unique delimiter.

Is there a way I can get a list instead of everything concatenated into one string?

Comment: I believe you need to change the highlighter formatter. See the paragraph starting "To change the fragmeter, formatter, order, or scorer used in highlighting ..." just below this place in the [Whoosh documentation](https://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/searching.html#whoosh.searching.Hit.highlights).

Answer (score 1):

You could just convert the highlighted string with the separator "..." to a list.

It's as simple as this:

```
highlights_list = hit.highlights("content").split("...")
```